# Algorithm for grouping unstructured text

Tags: algorithm, nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a lot of unstructured book data such as the following:

The Lord of the Rings J.R.R Tolkien

Tolkien Lord of the Rings Good condition

Very good condition Lord of the Rings jrr Tolkien

harry potter and the sorcerer's stone hardcover

JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone

The Stone of the Sorcerer by Bob Smith

I am trying to figure out which sentences represent the same book. For example the first 3 lines should be grouped together (Lord of the Rings), the next 2 should be grouped together (Harry Potter), and the last line is its own group (The Stone of the Sorcerer by Bob Smith). What is a good algorithm to do this?

(I have added "The Stone of the Sorcerer by Bob Smith" after the initial question to emphasise that simply matching two words is not distinct enough)

Answer (score 0):

I would filter out the neutral words (very, the, good, condition, ...) and match the titles based on the number of common words. If you identify initials, remove the dots. For efficient comparisons, sort the words alphabetically. Also lowercase everything.

```
jrr lord rings tolkien

lord rings tolkien 

jrr lord rings tolkien

harry potter sorcerer stone

harry jk potter rowling sorcerer
```

At least two words should match.

Comment: I have tried something like this, but issues arise when book titles are very similar. For example: 

JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone
The stone of the sorcerer by Bob Smith

These two books are not the same but they share 2 words, which under such an algorithm would be classified as the same.

Comment: @phil: will be even worse with two authors by the same name who used the same title.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cluster
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

    
sentences = [["The Lord of the Rings J.R.R Tolkien"],
            ["Lord of the Rings Good condition"],
            ["Very good condition Lord of the Rings jrr Tolkien"],
            ["harry potter and the sorcerer's stone hardcover"],
            ["JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone"]]



m = Word2Vec(sentences, size=50, min_count=1, sg=1)

def vectorizer(sent, m):
    vec=[]
    numw=0
    for w in sent:
        try:
            if numw == 0:
                vec = m[w]
            else:
                vec = np.add(vec, m[w])
            numw += 1 
        except:
            pass
    return np.asarray(vec)/numw

l=[]
for i in sentences:
    l.append(vectorizer(i,m))
X=np.array(l)


n_clusters = 2
clf = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters,
             max_iter=100,
             init='k-means++',
             n_init=1)
labels=clf.fit_predict(X)
print(labels)
for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    print(str(labels[index]) + ":" + str(sentence))
```

Result:

```
0:['The Lord of the Rings J.R.R Tolkien']
0:['Lord of the Rings Good condition']
1:['Very good condition Lord of the Rings jrr Tolkien']
0:["harry potter and the sorcerer's stone hardcover"]
1:["JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone"]
```

KMeans is almost certainly not be the best way to cluster any kind of text-data.  You may want to look at other clustering algos as well.  Agglomerative Clustering may be more robust in this case.

This is interesting.

For instance, if I change this...

```
for index, metric in enumerate(["cosine", "euclidean", "cityblock"]):
    clf = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters,
                                    linkage="average", affinity=metric)
```

I get this...

```
1:['The Lord of the Rings J.R.R Tolkien']
0:['Lord of the Rings Good condition']
0:['Very good condition Lord of the Rings jrr Tolkien']
0:["harry potter and the sorcerer's stone hardcover"]
0:["JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about performance (i.e. can take a while), what you can do is to compare each string to each other O(n ^ 2), and generate the following:

- longest consecutive character matches between 2 strings, ignoring punctuation and capitalization (i.e. only compare [ 0-9A-Za-z], skipping all other chars). (the key)
- the length of the above variable. (the score)
  The score would then govern which of the "longest string matches" to keep, and which to discard.

Given your list of books:

1. harry potter and the sorcerer's stone hardcover
2. JK rowling harry potter and the sorcerer's stone
3. The Stone of the Sorcerer by Bob Smith

Book 1 and 2 share: "harry potter and the sorcerers stone"
Book 1 and 3 share: " the sorcerer"
Because the first is longer than the 2nd, book 1 keeps only the index key "harry potter and the sorcerers stone".

Then we group the data on this key.
It will be fairly slow (very slow for large data set) but should give you decent accuracy.